# WP CLI: search and replace specific directory name of URL

Tags: wp-cli

I am trying to use wp cli (with regex) to search and replace.

**I want to change:**

domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/asdnbahsdjhgzw/picture.jpg

to

domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/picture.jpg

*So I want to get rid of the "asdnbahsdjhgzw" part.*

**Now I tried something like:**

```
wp search-replace "domain.com/wp-content/uploads/(\d)/(\d)/(\d*)/" "domain.com/wp-content/uploads/\$1/\$2/" --precise --all-tables --skip-columns=guid --regex
```

- (\d)/(\d)/ to match and "capture" the directory structure for media and thought I would be able to call them back in the replacement with /$1/$2/.
- (\d*)/ is to capture the random directory name,
  asdnbahsdjhgzw/, and don't call it back in the replacement.

**BUT**

Unfortunately, this isn´t working as I had hoped. I get the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I also tried the backslash before the (

```
/\(\d\)/\(\d\)/\(\d*\)/
```

But no luck.

Perhaps someone knows what could be the issue, apart from me not knowing WP CLI ;)

thanks!

Comment: When I try your command, it works without any problems. Using WP CLI 2.5.0 in Alpine with Bash.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Instead of using `"` to wrap your expressions, use `'`.</s>

Further experimenting shows me that this is *incorrect*—both `"` and `'` should work, as long as they're matched (ie, you don't accidentally try something like `wp search-replace "domain.com/wp-content/uploads/(\d)/(\d)/(\d*)/' "domain.com/wp-content/uploads/\$1/\$2/" --precise --all-tables --skip-columns=guid --regex`. (Note that the regex in that example starts with `"` and ends with `'`.)

I'm not deleting this answer because the info below, about the regex itself, still stands.

### The regex

Your regex looks wrong to me. `\d` will match a *single digit*, so it'd match, eg, `1`, `5`, etc, but *not* `2020` or `04`.

I'd recommend something like this:

```
wp search-replace
--dry-run
'domain.com/wp-content/uploads/(\d+)/(\d+)/[^/]+/'
'domain.com/wp-content/uploads/\$1/\$2/'
--precise --all-tables --skip-columns=guid --regex
```

(line breaks added for readability; all this should be on a single line)

The `[^/]+` will match everything *but* a `/` character in that last segment of the regex search. I also took out the `()` wrapping it since you're discarding it.

I also *strongly* recommend using the `--dry-run` argument with [`wp search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) first, to see what you'll be replacing.

**Edited again to add:** I've removed the text about my deeper dive into using `'` vs. `"` in `bash`, because it seems it was incorrect.

Comment: Can you (briefly) explain, why `'` will work and `"` not?

Comment: @kero  - I tried, but somehow I think I may have confused myself *more* on how `bash` works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you reproduce OP's problem? For me (in docker container running Alpine, Bash "GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl)") it worked with `"` ...

Comment: That's weird. When I tried it before, I thought it gave me the `bash` error OP was getting; but now when I try it, it works fine. It only gives me the error if I have an unmatched `"` (which makes sense to me). I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @kero Paging up through my shell's history, I see that I made it fail by not using quotes at all (which of course throws the error).